# how to override function in inherit controller Odoo 12 only using in this module

Tags: python, odoo-12

My core controller class:

```
class ReportController(http.Controller):
   @http.route('/report/download_document/<reportname>/<docids>', type='http', auth="user")
   @serialize_exception
   def download_document(self, **kw):
```

My inherit class:

```
from odoo.addons.my_module.controllers.main import ReportController as RC

class ReportControllerProject(RC):
# Override method: download_document in my_module
   @http.route('/report/download_document/<reportname>/<docids>', type='http', auth="user")
   @serialize_exception
   def download_document(self, **kw):
```

But when I use action to download_document in another module it still uses the function of the inherit class.

I want this function to be used only in the inherit class of this module, not everywhere, so what am I gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

The other modules will use the function of the module they are dependant on.
So in the manifest of the module where you want to use the overridden function make sure to depend from my_module.

```
__manifest__.py
.
.
.
'depends': [
    'my_module',
],
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you for that but I've already depended my_module before

Comment: @NgoDucHan your answer and your question does not match, you should change your question because the override was working, ask about how to use overridden function instead of how to override.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this situation, I just use condition and call super() function to execute this overriden funtion

```
from odoo.addons.my_module.controllers.main import ReportController as RC

class ReportControllerProject(RC):
    # Override method: download_document in my_module
    @http.route('/report/download_document/<reportname>/<docids>', type='http', auth="user")
    @serialize_exception
    def download_document(self, **kw):
        *some code here*
        if <condition>:
           *some code here*
           return *something here*
        else:
           return super(ReportControllerProject, self).download_document(**kw)
```